# Send Facebook Message using Spring Social

Tags: java, facebook, spring, spring-social

Is it possible to send Facebook Messages (NOT on their wall, but a "Message") to friends using Spring Social?

If yes, which API do I use? If there is no such support in Spring Social, what's the best way to do so from a Java application?

Comment: also posted on http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?118186-Send-Facebook-Message-using-Spring-Social

Comment: Your question has been answered on the mailing list, if the solution works it might be useful to repeat the answer here.

Comment: unfortunately, that is not the answer to what I am looking. Just added a comment/reply to clarify that. However, I have thought of another way that I am gonna post as an answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way out that I could think of is to send an email at the ID : **{facebook-id}@facebook.com**, as it ultimately sends a Facebook message to the user.

Comment: What should be placed on the "from" email? And how will the user get the message from the App?

Answer (score 0):

For what I know, Facebook doesn't allow to send messages (and also asking friendship) with its API. So I think that you can't send messages to Facebook in a clean way. What you can do is make a bot that navigate the page on the server side and click buttons without user interaction. But I think that it's not so legal...

Answer (score -3):

I would take a look at this site

http://www.springsource.org/

This website has all the information you need to get started with SpringSource. Here's a link to their forums

http://forum.springsource.org/index.php

Comment: nothing could be found (at least by me) on their website, though.

Comment: This answer really doesn't add any value. I'm sure the OP is aware of both of those links.